# What`s .Net core alternative of DataSource attribute for mstest?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, mstest

From the below, got to know that DataSource attribute is no more supported on .net core projects of MSTest. So what`s the alternative to this?

Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2019

Info:
.NET Core does not support the DataSource attribute. If you try to access test data in this way in a .NET Core or UWP unit test project, you'll see an error similar to "'TestContext' does not contain a definition for 'DataRow' and no accessible extension method 'DataRow' accepting a first argument of type 'TestContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Answer (score 2):

### September 7th, 2020 - No workaround

There is an open issue [issue-233](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/233) about this and no comments on when it can be fixed. There are some work-arounds:

#### DynamicDateAttribute (CSV Example)

```
private static string[] SplitCsv(string input)
{
    var csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input))
    {
        string value = match.Value;
        if (value.Length == 0)
        {
            list.Add(string.Empty);
        }

        list.Add(value.TrimStart(','));
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}

private static IEnumerable<string[]> GetData()
{
    IEnumerable<string> rows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Resources\NameAddressCityStateZip.csv").Skip(1);
    foreach (string row in rows)
    {
        yield return SplitCsv(row);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
//x [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"Resources\NameAddressCityStateZip.csv", "NameAddressCityStateZip#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void TestMethod1(string input, string expected)
{
    // Arrange
    //x string input = _testContext.Properties["Data"].ToString(); //x _testContext.DataRow["Data"].ToString();
    //x string expected = _testContext.Properties["Expected"].ToString(); //x _testContext.DataRow["Expected"].ToString();
    var parser = _serviceProvider.GetService<Parser>();

    // Act
    string actual = parser.MultiParser(input, ModeType.NameAddressCityStateZipCountry).ToString();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

but there are drawbacks to it.

#### Port it yourself code

As exibited in the comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/pull/1050#issuecomment-447609178)

#### Wait for the implementation

Comment: @Kataras - Thanks! I need to read xml data file, is there a way I can write a special class and use it as an attribute on my test methods(MS test2)? If yes, could you enlighten me?